# Script in my html page not working when i serve it through the 'http' server in Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I am handling my '/' route in the 'http' server and i'm serving the index.html file in this way-

```
if(parsedUrl.pathname === '/') {
            fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(err, fileResponse){
                if(err){
                    console.log('Error');
                    res.writeHeader(404, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
                    res.write('There was an error!');
                } else {
                    console.log('No error');
                    res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    res.write(fileResponse);
                }
                res.end();
            });

            //fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html').pipe(res);
            break;
        }
```

This is my index.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Explorer</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

</head>

<script>
    alert('hello');
    var fileExplorerApp = angular.module('explorerApp', []);
    fileExplorerApp.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
        console.log('Angular working 1');

        var currentPath = '';
        $scope.reload = function (newPath, back) {
            if (back) {
                currentPath = newPath;
            } else {
                if (currentPath === '') {
                    currentPath = newPath;
                } else {
                    currentPath = currentPath + '/' + newPath;
                }
            }
            console.log('Newpath- ' + currentPath);

            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:3000/list_dir?path=' + currentPath})
                    .success(function(response){
                        console.log('Angular working 2');
                        $scope.filesAndFolders = response.data;
                        $scope.currentPath = currentPath;
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log('Error in $http- '+error);
                    });

        }

        $scope.back = function () {
            var prevPath = currentPath.substring(0, currentPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
            console.log('Path after substring- ' + prevPath);
            console.log('Prevpath when back clicked- ' + prevPath);
            $scope.reload(prevPath, true);

        }

        $scope.reload('F:/', false);
    });
</script>

<body ng-app="explorerApp" ng-controller="MyController">

<div class="ui container">
    <h1 id="currentPath">Current Directory- {{ currentPath }}</h1>
    <button ng-if="currentPath !== 'F:/'"
            ng-click="back()"
            class="ui left labeled icon button">
        <i class="left arrow icon"></i>
        Back
    </button>
    <div class="ui list">
        <a class="item"
           ng-repeat="item in filesAndFolders"
           ng-click="reload(item.name, false)"
           ng-href="{{item.type === 'file' ? '/get_file?path='+currentPath+'/'+item.name : ''}}">
            <i ng-if="item.type === 'folder'" class="folder icon"></i>
            <i ng-if="item.type === 'file'" class="file icon"></i>
            {{ item.name }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, there is some problem with this code. The script doesn't execute somehow. Please tell me whats wrong with this code?

PS: i know i can use Express to make this easier but this is actually an assignment given to me and it's mentioned that i have to use 'http' module provided by node to handle the routes and not Express of any other framework for that matter.

Comment: what messages get printed to your server console?  what messages get printed to your browser console?

Comment: Chances are your script starts executing before external scripts are loaded. I would put the whole script content into a function added as a `load` event handler: `window.addEventListener('load', function() { // your script here } );`

Comment: Nothing gets printed. Neither in my server console nor the browser console.
I think @WiktorZychla is right. Lemme try his method out.

Comment: `$http(..)` function returns promise which doesn't have success method. It should be `$http(..).then(...)` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage

Comment: I changed it to 

`$http.get('http://localhost:3000/list_dir?path=' + currentPath)

                        .then(function (response) {

                            console.log('Angular working 2'+ response);

                            $scope.filesAndFolders = response.data;

                            $scope.currentPath = currentPath;

                        }, function (error) {

                            console.log('Error in $http- ' + error);

                        });`

window.addEventListener.. also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `success` in 1.6 version of angular. I changed to then and catch syntax.

```
  $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/list_dir?path=' + currentPath})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('Angular working 2');
        $scope.filesAndFolders = response.data;
        $scope.currentPath = currentPath;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error in $http- ' + error);
    });
```

Another issues that you might face are CORS but I can't see your full code to tell.